# Systemd stop ssh-agent unable to find user-runtime-dir@ssh-agent.service

Tags: systemd, ssh-agent

I've got the following service to start and stop the ssh-agent. Which I intend to start/enable for --user.

**Problem** is I get the error message that user-runtime-dir@ssh-agent.service doesn't exist.
But it does.
Strangley I can run systemctl status user-runtime-dir@ssh-agent.service but not with the --user flag
So to me it seems that user-runtime-dir@%i can't be used on a user-level service.

Am I doing something wrong or anyone an idea how to stop the ssh-agent properly with systemd?

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH key agent
After=systemd-user-sessions.service user-runtime-dir@%i.service dbus.service
Requires=user-runtime-dir@%i.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/ssh-agent.socket
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: `user-runtime-dir@.service` creates the runtime directory for a *user* that can then be used by that user's services.  Just remove all those dependencies. When `ssh-agent.service` is started as a user service then all those things are guaranteed to be there.

Comment: ofc when I remove the dependencies the service starts the ssh-agent but I want to stop the agent when I logout and not do it with a script like .zlogout or other.